# R: Count number of objects in list

Tags: list, r, count

Can someone recommend a function that can allow me to count and return the number of items in a list?

```
library(stringr)

l <- strsplit(words, "a")

if(# number of items in list l < 1) 
  next
```

Comment: set.seed(123)
l <- replicate(20, runif(sample(1:10,1)), simplify = FALSE)
unlist(lapply(l,length))

Answer (score 195, accepted):

[length(x)](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/length.html)

> Get or set the length of vectors (including lists) and factors, and of any other R object for which a method has been defined.

[lengths(x)](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/lengths.html)

> Get the length of each element of a list or atomic vector (is.atomic) as an integer or numeric vector.

Answer (score 100):

Advice for `R` newcomers like me : beware, the following is a list of **a single object** :

```
> mylist <- list (1:10)
> length (mylist)
[1] 1
```

In such a case you are not looking for the length of the list, but of its first element :

```
> length (mylist[[1]])
[1] 10
```

This is a "true" list :

```
> mylist <- list(1:10, rnorm(25), letters[1:3])
> length (mylist)
[1] 3
```

Also, it seems that `R` considers a data.frame as a list :

```
> df <- data.frame (matrix(0, ncol = 30, nrow = 2))
> typeof (df)
[1] "list"
```

In such a case you may be interested in `ncol()` and `nrow()` rather than `length()` :

```
> ncol (df)
[1] 30
> nrow (df)
[1] 2
```

Though `length()` will also work (but it's a trick when your data.frame has only one column) :

```
> length (df)
[1] 30
> length (df[[1]])
[1] 2
```

Answer (score 13):

I spent ages trying to figure this out but it is simple! You can use `length(·)`.               `length(mylist)` will tell you the number of objects `mylist` contains.

... and just realised someone had already answered this- sorry!

Answer (score 13):

Let's create an empty list (not required, but good to know):

```
> mylist <- vector(mode="list")
```

Let's put some stuff in it - 3 components/indexes/tags (whatever you want to call it) each with differing amounts of elements:

```
> mylist <- list(record1=c(1:10),record2=c(1:5),record3=c(1:2))
```

If you are interested in just the number of components in a list use:

```
> length(mylist)
[1] 3
```

If you are interested in the length of elements in a specific component of a list use: (both reference the same component here)

```
length(mylist[[1]])
[1] 10
length(mylist[["record1"]]
[1] 10
```

If you are interested in the length of all elements in all components of the list use:

```
> sum(sapply(mylist,length))
[1] 17
```

Answer (score 10):

You can also use `unlist()`, which is often useful for handling lists:

```
> mylist <- list(A = c(1:3), B = c(4:6), C = c(7:9))

> mylist
$A
[1] 1 2 3

$B
[1] 4 5 6

$C
[1] 7 8 9

> unlist(mylist)
A1 A2 A3 B1 B2 B3 C1 C2 C3 
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 

> length(unlist(mylist))
[1] 9
```

unlist() is a simple way of executing other functions on lists as well, such as:

```
> sum(mylist)
Error in sum(mylist) : invalid 'type' (list) of argument

> sum(unlist(mylist))
[1] 45
```