# Generating a vector of the number of items in each list item

Tags: list, r

I have a list containing 98 items. But each item contains 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 or 5 character strings.

I know how to get the length of the list and in fact [someone has asked the question before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1740524/r-count-number-of-objects-in-list) and got voted down for presumably asking such an easy question.

But I want a vector that is 98 elements long with each element being an integer from 0 to 5 telling me how many character strings there are in each list item.
I was expecting the following to work but it did not.

```
lapply(name.of.list,length())
```

From my question you will see that I do not really know the nomeclature of lists and items. Feel free to straighten me out.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Farrel, I do not exactly follow as 'item' is not an R type. Maybe you have a `list` of length 98 where each element is a vector of character string?

In that case, consider this:

```
R> fl <- list(A=c("un", "deux"), B=c("one"), C=c("eins", "zwei", "drei"))
R> lapply(fl, function(x) length(x))
$A
[1] 2

$B
[1] 1

$C
[1] 3
R> do.call(rbind, lapply(fl, function(x) length(x)))
  [,1]
A    2
B    1
C    3
R>
```

So there is you vector of the length of your list, telling you how many strings each list element has.  Note the last `do.call(rbind, someList)` as we got a list back from `lapply`.

If, on the other hand, you want to count the length of all the strings at each list position, replace the simple `length(x)` with a new function counting the characters:

```
R> lapply(fl, function(x) { sapply(x, function(y) nchar(y)) } )
$A
  un deux 
   2    4 

$B
one 
  3 

$C
eins zwei drei 
   4    4    4 

R>
```

If that is not want you want, maybe you could mock up some example input data?

***Edit:***:  In response to your comments, what you wanted is probably:

```
R> do.call(rbind, lapply(fl, length))
  [,1]
A    2
B    1
C    3
R>
```

Note that I pass in `length`, the name of a function, and not `length()`, the (displayed) body of a function.  Because that is easy to mix up, I simply apply almost always wrap an anonymous function around as in my first answer.

And yes, this can also be done with just `sapply` or even some of the `**ply` functions:

```
R> sapply(fl, length)
A B C 
2 1 3 
R> lapply(fl, length)
[1] 2 1 3
R>
```

Comment: The first way you did it is what I want. Let me go try that.

Comment: Yip, it worked. Fantastic. In fact sapply worked even better because it made a simple single vector which I can now go and cbind onto a preexisting dataframe. Now can you explain to me how lapply(name.of.list,length()) and lapply(name.of.list,function(x) length(x)) are different.

Comment: Please see the additional edit at my answer -- in essence `length` is different from `length()` and you want the former.

Answer (score 10):

All this seems very complicated - there is a function specifically doing what you were asking for:

```
lengths  #note the plural "s"
```

Using Dirks sample data:

```
fl <- list(A=c("un", "deux"), B=c("one"), C=c("eins", "zwei", "drei"))
lengths(fl)
```

will return a named integer vector:

```
A B C 
2 1 3
```

Comment: If the list items are tibbles, how do you get the length of the tibble?

Answer (score 0):

The code below accepts a list and returns a vector of lengths:

```
x = c("vectors", "matrices", "arrays", "factors", "dataframes", "formulas", 
      "shingles", "datesandtimes", "connections", "lists")
xl = list(x)
fnx = function(xl){length(unlist(strsplit(x, "")))}
lv = sapply(x, fnx)
```