# R data.table and dplyr - count number of elements in each list

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I have a tidyr function (if it can me solved here would be great) which takes a data.table object and sees if a keyword (kw - here it is 'agree') is mentioned any times. This returns me a data.table vector of lists with anytime it mentions it:

```
    test <-  ptadfmatching[,"text"] %>% 
      mutate(new_var =   str_extract_all(text, regex(kw[x], ignore_case = TRUE))   )%>% 
      select(new_var)
```

The result is something like this

```
> test
                         new_var
                           <list>
 1:             AGREE,Agree,agree
 2:             Agree,Agree,Agree
 3:                   agree,Agree
 4:                   agree,Agree
 5:                         Agree
 6:                         agree
 7:                   Agree,Agree
 8:             Agree,Agree,Agree
 9:             Agree,Agree,agree
10:
```

Question - how do I get length of each list in 'test' (without a loop).

Comment: `lengths(test$new_var)`

Comment: if you need that within the data.table, then easily `test[,count := lengths(new_var)]`

Comment: yeah I tried this just gives me ones

Comment: Should this be duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1740524/r-count-number-of-objects-in-list/1740562#1740562?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `lengths()`, which is probably what you wanted. `?lengths` shows:

> Get the length of each element of a list or atomic vector (is.atomic) as an integer or numeric vector.

A simple example:

```r
test <- data.table::as.data.table(structure(list(new_var = list(c("AGREE", "Agree", "agree"), c("Agree", "Agree", "Agree"), c("agree", "Agree"), c("agree", "Agree"), "Agree", "agree", c("Agree", "Agree"), c("Agree", "Agree", "Agree"), c("Agree", "Agree", "agree"), character(0))), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame")))
# dplyr
test |> 
  dplyr::mutate(count = lengths(new_var))
#>               new_var count
#>  1: AGREE,Agree,agree     3
#>  2: Agree,Agree,Agree     3
#>  3:       agree,Agree     2
#>  4:       agree,Agree     2
#>  5:             Agree     1
#>  6:             agree     1
#>  7:       Agree,Agree     2
#>  8: Agree,Agree,Agree     3
#>  9: Agree,Agree,agree     3
#> 10:                       0
# data.table
test[, count := lengths(new_var)]
test
#>               new_var count
#>  1: AGREE,Agree,agree     3
#>  2: Agree,Agree,Agree     3
#>  3:       agree,Agree     2
#>  4:       agree,Agree     2
#>  5:             Agree     1
#>  6:             agree     1
#>  7:       Agree,Agree     2
#>  8: Agree,Agree,Agree     3
#>  9: Agree,Agree,agree     3
#> 10:                       0
```

<sup>Created on 2023-08-01 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: thanks, I tried, it just gives me a length (in mutate) of the entire vector

Comment: Note it is `lengths` not `length`.

Comment: LiangZhang, I suggest you demo with representative data, try `test <- data.table::as.data.table(structure(list(new_var = list(c("AGREE", "Agree", "agree"), c("Agree", "Agree", "Agree"), c("agree", "Agree"), c("agree", "Agree"), "Agree", "agree", c("Agree", "Agree"), c("Agree", "Agree", "Agree"), c("Agree", "Agree", "agree"), character(0))), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame")))`.

Comment: @user3685724, that is okay. It can be very misleading for the first time.